# How i can check user availability without postbacking of page to server?

Tags: asp.net

I have made a user signup form in asp.net. I want to check the user availability from user table made in sqlserver without postbacking of the page to the server.
Checking user availability when the focus out from textbox or during text change.

Please provide me code or source in vb language if possible.

Comment: Why do you need to check user availablity while changing a text in TextBox? How can user be unavailable and change text at the same time? Anyway you need to use AJAX, the simpliest method is using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From client-side, the only option is AJAX web services using JavaScript in the front end and an ASMX in the backend: http://dotnetslackers.com/columns/ajax/ASPNETAjaxWebService.aspx, or using the pagemethods approach: http://aspalliance.com/1922

HTH.